# Intento realizar un POST desde Angular a un servicio desarrollado en ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angular5

Hola buenas comunidad estoy teniendo problemas al realizar un POST desde Angular, tengo un servicio web desarrollado con ASP.NET Core 2. Mi método post del servicio es el siguiente:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostTipoPago(TipoPago tipoPago)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.TipoPago.Add(tipoPago);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(tipoPago);
    }
```

La clase `TipoPago` es la siguiente :

```
public class TipoPago
{
    [Key]
    public int TipoPagoId { get; set; }

    [MinLength(5), MaxLength(25), Required]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [MinLength(10), MaxLength(100), Required]
    public string Detalle { get; set; }
}
```

Ahora paso a mostrarles como intento desde Angular enviar los datos para que los reciba mi metodo del servicio.

```
addTipoPago(tipoPago: TipoPago)
{
var datos = JSON.stringify(tipoPago);
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return this.http.post<TipoPago>('http://localhost:52480/api/TipoPagos', datos, { headers });
}
```

y el modelo `TipoPago` desde Angular es el siguiente:

```
    export class TipoPago
{
  TipoPagoId: number;
  Nombre: string;
  Detalle: string;
}
```

y el error que tengo cuando ejecuto la peticion es la siguiente :

[image: ...]

En la imagen se ve que en primer lugar imprimo el dato que enviaría al método del servicio, y lo que me esta pasando es que me devuelve un error como si estuviese mandando mal los datos, de tal forma que me dice que los campos son requeridos, como si estuviese recibiendo un valor vacío. No encuentro cual puede ser el problema si alguien podría ayudarme sería de gran ayuda. Saludos

Comment: dale un console.log(tipoPago); antes de let headers... Me late que está vacío

Comment: pone un break point en el método post y ahí revisa si llegan o no los datos

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder y ayudarme, por suerte logre resolver mi problema. Me guié de aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026598/angularjs2-post-method-to-asp-net-core-passes-empty-object

Comment: Es un problema de formato y se soluciona agregando [FromBody] en el método del servicio. Saludos a todos